# How to create JSON file extracting specific object fields, basing on object with all fields annotated with @JsonProperty - JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a class like this in one of the microservices (I cannot change it):

```
public class MyClass {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    String gender;
    List<SomeObject> some objects;

    @JsonProperty("name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
        public String getAge() {
            return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("gender")
        public String getGender() {
            return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("someObjects")
        public List<SomeObject> getSomeObjects() {
            return someObjects;
    }
}
```

My task is to create JSON file basing on data from that class, but this file should only contain
'age' and 'name' property, and from SomeObject I should also extract part of the data to create a list.

I don't know how can I 'turn off' the properties, that I don't needed. Is it possible?

Comment: You can create a custom serializer and just include `age` and `name` property: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Thanks, now I know that it is possible to create shorter JSON based on original class :) Anyway, I decided to use BendaThierry's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using Jackson `ObjectMapper`.

Add the dependency, with Maven, inside your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Create your custom entity without the fields you don't need on your client side :

```
public class CustomPerson {
    String name;
    Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
        public String getAge() {
            return name;
    }
}
```

Use ObjectMapper to save any object or list of objects of `CustomPerson` POJO :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// one person object saved in person.json file :
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("path/to/person.json"), person);

// many person objecs saved in persons.json file :
objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get("persons.json").toFile(), persons);
```

The rest is trivial, you'll get it easily.

Comment: he said, he can not change the class

Comment: I said create another class, not change it.

Comment: Thanks, creating another class helps with my task.

Comment: @Anastazja If my post has helped you, consider upvoting it ;) and welcome to StackOverflow.com

Comment: I was trying to upvote, but I received such a msg: "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."